# Lucene not returning offsets for complex queries

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene for searching in my android app but when I run a complex query it doesn't return offsets for the terms.

For example:

```
+content:"word" +(personid:NULL personid:123)
+content:"word" +(personid:NULL)
+content:"word" -personid:123
```

will not return any offsets for the "word".

```
+content:word
```

Will return offsets.

here is what I am storing in each field

```
 doc.add(new Field(PERSON_ID_FIELD, request.getPersonId(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
 // we don't actually store the content here
 doc.add(new Field(CONTENT_FIELD, request.getContent(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_OFFSETS));
```

Am I missing something? Is there something I need to do in the query to get offsets back?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you trying to retrieve offsets?

Comment: I am getting the TermVector for the content filed, and then asking for the offsets for each term in the query.

Comment: @jpountz Thanks just the question I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one tries to get an offset from the content field for the term with `personid` it doesn't return any offsets. Then by not looping through the entire term list from the query one never gets to the content term of the query. Thus no offsets are returned.